# ¿Como puedo marcar una check box con un if?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Saludos, tengo la siguiente situación:

Tengo un **if** que como objetivo quiero que marque un **radio button**, he intentado con scripts pero no me da resultado.

```
<div class="funkyradio">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM permiso WHERE user = '" . $object['usuario'] . "' AND fk_actions = '" . $objetoA1['id'] . "';";
$query = $cone->sqlSeleccion($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($queryA2) == 1) {
?>
    <script>
        $("#radioA").prop("checked", true);
    </script>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <script>
        $("#radioB").prop("checked", true);
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
<div class="funkyradio-success">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioA" />
    <label for="radioA">Aprobado</label>
</div>
<div class="funkyradio-danger">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioB" />
    <label for="radioB">Denegado</label>
</div>
```

Gracias :)

Comment: Quieres que se selecione solo 1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La solución fue agregar los `$(function () {code...}`:

```
<div class="funkyradio">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM permiso WHERE user = '" . $object['usuario'] . "' AND fk_actions = '" . $objetoA1['id'] . "';";
$query = $cone->sqlSeleccion($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($queryA2) == 1) {
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
         $("#radioA").prop("checked", true);
    });
</script>
<?php
} else {
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#radioB").prop("checked", true);
    });
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<div class="funkyradio-success">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioA" />
    <label for="radioA">Aprobado</label>
</div>
<div class="funkyradio-danger">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioB" />
    <label for="radioB">Denegado</label>
</div>
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

Se puede solucionar de una manera más elegante y sin usar Javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="funkyradio">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM permiso WHERE user = '" . $object['usuario'] . "' AND fk_actions = '" . $objetoA1['id'] . "';";
$query = $cone->sqlSeleccion($sql); 
$aprobado = mysqli_num_rows($queryA2) == 1;
?>

<div class="funkyradio-success">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioA" <?php echo $aprobado ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
    <label for="radioA">Aprobado</label>
</div>
<div class="funkyradio-danger">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioB"<?php echo !$aprobado ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
    <label for="radioB">Denegado</label>
</div>
```